# Find index of object in array with specific value for specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object in which I need to find a particular item index number. Below is my object:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Grayscale",
    "mode": "average"
  }, {
    "type": "Sepia"
  }, {
    "type": "Invert",
    "invert": true
  }, {
    "type": "Convolute",
    "opaque": false,
    "matrix": [1, 1, 1, 1, 0.7, -1, -1, -1, -1]
  }, {
    "type": "Convolute",
    "opaque": false,
    "matrix": [0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0]
  }, {
    "type": "Brownie"
  }, {
    "type": "Brightness",
    "brightness": 0.35
  }
]
```

For example, I need to find the index number of the item which has the value `Invert` for the `type` property. So in this case, the output should be `2`. I only need to search the values of the `type` key.

Comment: "I have only type key value to find index" elaborate please

Comment: Do you only need to find the first instance where type is Invert, or could the array hold many of these objects

Comment: so you want to loop through each object in the array until you find one whose "type" property equals "Invert", and then you want to output the index in the array at which that item occurs. If you need to be able to find more than one occurrence, continue your loop. Doesn't sound too hard, have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: i mean to find index number of item i have key("type":) value and in above example value is **Invert**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `findIndex` method, by passing a provided *callback* function as argument.

```js
let arr = [ {"type":"Grayscale","mode":"average"}, {"type":"Sepia"}, {"type":"Invert","invert":true}, {"type":"Convolute","opaque":false,"matrix":[1,1,1,1,0.7,-1,-1,-1,-1]}, {"type":"Convolute","opaque":false,"matrix":[0,-1,0,-1,5,-1,0,-1,0]}, {"type":"Brownie"}, {"type":"Brightness","brightness":0.35} ], key = 'type';
console.log(arr.findIndex(elem => elem[key] == 'Invert'));
```

Comment: What about if the OP  want `'Type'` instead of  `'Invert'` ?

Comment: only worth noting that this is not supported in any version of Internet Explorer - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex, so if you need to support IE, you'll need the polyfill shown in the link

Comment: Why did you remove the object destructuring??? It was the best part of the answer! (since `findIndex` is quite well known...)

Comment: @ADyson  When do you think we could look forward, and just bury this browser?.  Anyone who needs to code for IE, should know that polyfills & transpiling is something they need to worry about.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, because I think the OP wants the property dinamically given.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short snippet for the code.

```js
var sample = [{"type":"Grayscale","mode":"average"},{"type":"Sepia"},{"type":"Invert","invert":true},{"type":"Convolute","opaque":false,"matrix":[1,1,1,1,0.7,-1,-1,-1,-1]},{"type":"Convolute","opaque":false,"matrix":[0,-1,0,-1,5,-1,0,-1,0]},{"type":"Brownie"},{"type":"Brightness","brightness":0.35}]  

function findIndex(data, keyfield, value){
  
  return data.indexOf(data.find(function(el,index){
    return el[keyfield] === value;
  }));
}

console.log(findIndex(sample, 'type', 'Invert'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use underscore or loadash(_) package. It has multiple functionality support for array operations.

```
const _ = require('lodash')

let your_array=  [
      {"type":"Grayscale","mode":"average"},
      {"type":"Sepia"},
      {"type":"Invert","invert":true},
      {"type":"Convolute","opaque":false,"matrix":[1,1,1,1,0.7,-1,-1,-1,-1]},
      {"type":"Convolute","opaque":false,"matrix":[0,-1,0,-1,5,-1,0,-1,0]},
      {"type":"Brownie"},
      {"type":"Brightness","brightness":0.35}
    ];
    let objectIndex = _.findIndex(your_array, each_element=> each_element.type == "Invert");
    alert(objectIndex)
```

Comment: Link for lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10